# Makefile - iterate over list of files - first file missed

Tags: cmd, foreach, makefile, gnu-make

I've got a file containing a list of source files that looks like this:

```
SRCS = src/main.c \
src/main.h
```

Then in my makefile I have a target like so to create a .TCL file that references the SRCS files:

```
create_app.tcl: .platform.done
    echo setws $(WORKSPACE) > $@
    echo platform active {$(PROJ_NAME)_platform} >> $@
    echo app create -name $(PROJ_NAME)_app -template {Empty Application(C)} >> $@   
    echo app config -name $(PROJ_NAME)_app -add libraries m >> $@
    $(foreach file, $(SRCS), echo importsources -name $(PROJ_NAME)_app -path {$(realpath $(file))} -soft-link & >> $@) true
```

The 'foreach' line misses off the first source file from my list and i'm struggling to see why. So my TCL ends up like this:

```
setws ws
platform active {test_platform} 
app create -name test_app -template {Empty Application(C)}  
app config -name test_app -add libraries m 
importsources -name test_app -path {C:/git/dev_aph/software/test/src/main.h} -soft-link
```

When it should end up  like this:

```
setws ws 
platform active {test_platform} 
app create -name test_app -template {Empty Application(C)}  
app config -name test_app -add libraries m 
importsources -name test_app -path {C:/git/dev_aph/software/test/src/main.c} -soft-link 
importsources -name test_app -path {C:/git/dev_aph/software/test/src/main.h} -soft-link
```

Can anyone point out what i'm doing incorrectly here? Sure I could just add the first file twice but i'd rather understand what i've got wrong and fix it.
Thanks.

Update:

Trying Renaud's suggestion:

```
make create_app.tcl
echo setws ws > create_app.tcl
echo platform active {test_platform} >> create_app.tcl
echo app create -name test_app -template {Empty Application(C)} >> create_app.tcl
echo app config -name test_app -add libraries m >> create_app.tcl
for p in C:/git/dev_aph/software/test/src/main.c C:/git/dev_aph/software/test/src/main.h; do \
        echo "importsources -name test_app -path {$p} -soft-link &" >> create_app.tcl; \
done
p was unexpected at this time.
make: *** [../../scripts/vitis.mk:38: create_app.tcl] Error 255
```

If I change the loop variable to be %%p:

```
make create_app.tcl
echo setws ws > create_app.tcl
echo platform active {test_platform} >> create_app.tcl
echo app create -name test_app -template {Empty Application(C)} >> create_app.tcl
echo app config -name test_app -add libraries m >> create_app.tcl
for %%p in C:/git/dev_aph/software/test/src/main.c C:/git/dev_aph/software/test/src/main.h; do \
        echo "importsources -name test_app -path {$p} -soft-link &" >> create_app.tcl; \
done
C:/git/dev_aph/software/test/src/main.c was unexpected at this time.
make: *** [../../scripts/vitis.mk:38: create_app.tcl] Error 255
```

Another update:
Got it working as intended by modifying the 'foreach':

```
$(foreach file, $(SRCS), echo importsources -name $(PROJ_NAME)_app -path {$(realpath $(file))} -soft-link >> $@ &) true
```

I've moved the & the other side of the $@ as I noticed the first source file in the list was getting echo'd to the command line rather than to the target.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `foreach` as a replacement for a `for`-loop inside a recipe. The rule how `make` expands and parses a recipe inside a rule is to first substitute *all* variables and functions and *then* to pass the resulting string to single shell invocations, line by line as written in the makefile. What you need to recognize though, is that `foreach` DOES NOT produce anything else but a *space*-separated list of strings, so your depiction of singled out lines per iteration is the wrong mental picture of this function. Its just a string, really. In your case the result of the `foreach` will look like this:

```
echo importsources -name test_app -path {src/main.c} -soft-link & >> create_app.tcl echo importsources -name test_app -path {src/main.h} -soft-link & >> create_app.tcl true
```

Notice the double `echo` in the line - I am too weak in shell programming to really judge the validity of the syntax of this statement but I think its funny that it works at all. A possible workaround is the definition of newline and tabulator characters which you could prepend to the generator string in the `foreach`, but I think the more common and easier to understand approach is to write a true `for`loop in shell syntax.

In case you nevertheless want to try the `make` based solution (and learn a bit about dynamically generating `makefile` portions):

```
empty := #    
define newline :=
$(empty)
$(empty)
endef

SRCS = src/main.c \
src/main.h 

create_app.tcl: .platform.done
    echo setws $(WORKSPACE) > $@
    echo platform active {$(PROJ_NAME)_platform} >> $@
    echo app create -name $(PROJ_NAME)_app -template {Empty Application(C)} >> $@   
    echo app config -name $(PROJ_NAME)_app -add libraries m >> $@
    $(foreach file, $(SRCS), echo importsources -name $(PROJ_NAME)_app -path {$(realpath $(file))} -soft-link & >> $@$(newline))
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in comments you are mixing make functions and shell functions and this is wrong. If your file paths don't have spaces, try:

```
PATHS := $(realpath $(SRCS))

create_app.tcl: .platform.done
    ...
    for p in $(PATHS); do \
      echo "importsources -name $(PROJ_NAME)_app -path {$$p} -soft-link &" >> $@; \
    done
```

Do not forget the trailing `\` characters (line continuation) and the `$$p`.

Comment: Is this a `map` function in shell syntax in disguise?

Comment: Kind of. `printf` iterates over all parameters. At each iteration it consumes as many of them as there are format specifications in the format string. In this case we have only one format specifications (`%s` for string). So it will print one line per parameter. I just realize that this will work only if `$(PROJ_NAME)` does not contain other format specifications. This is likely but I will edit my answer to avoid potential issues.

Comment: Thanks. Tried this suggestion but got: 
printf: warning: ignoring excess arguments, starting with `importsources'. I probably should've mentioned i'm on Windows using GNUWIN.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I assumed bash built-in `printf`, which is a wrong assumption. Let me fix that.

Comment: Now getting "p was unexpected at this time". Trying some other stuff, will update the main post.

Comment: You forgot the semicolon (`;`) between `for p in $(PATHS)` and `do`.

Comment: Sorry, yes. Realised that and re-tried with same result but forgot to update the post.

Comment: OK, this means that the shell your make uses is something that does not understand `for` loops. Probably not a variant of the bourne shell, more likely a Windows thing. Without knowing what it is it will be difficult to suggest recipes... If you add `$(info SHELL = $(SHELL))` as first line of your Makefile and you run make again, what do you see?

Comment: SHELL = command.com. I've managed to get it working using the foreach loop (updated original post) even though i'm being told this is not a good approach.

Comment: `command.com` is the old MS-DOS command interpreter, it is extremely limited. If you plan to do moderately complex things with make you should probably consider upgrading to, at least, `sh`.

Comment: @Adi when trying to write platform independent shell instructions in `make`, there are few good approaches, and they are restricted to the most basic things. `for` loops surely expand far beyond what one can formulate platform independent, so it boils down to a choose-your-poison approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's suggestions. I'm going to post my solution to the original problem. I know it has been mentioned that this is not the best approach but it has achieved the result I was looking for.

Got it working as intended by modifying the 'foreach':

```
$(foreach file, $(SRCS), echo importsources -name $(PROJ_NAME)_app -path {$(realpath $(file))} -soft-link >> $@ &) true
```

I've moved the & the other side of the $@ as I noticed the first source file in the list was getting echo'd to the command line rather than to the target.

Comment: Well yes.  `&` is a command terminator in the shell language, similar to `;`, but causing the command to be run in the background.  It's not clear to me why you chose that for your recipe, but if indeed you mean it to be a terminator, and especially if you care about the order of the output, then `;` would be a better choice.

Comment: I've probably not tagged this correctly. I'm running GNU make in a Windows command shell so `&` allows me to combine multiple commands.